# How does the standard topology on $R$ induce a structure on $R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having a hard time seeing how does the standard topology on $R$ induces the structure on the set of real numbers such that it give us the real number line! The definition of a topology on a set seems so weak that it seems it doesn't impose enough restrictions on a set so that the set becomes continuous. So does the continuity of the real numbers assumed before defining the topology, so then what is the use of the topology,or we can give the structure of the real numbers 'the continuity' by imposing a topology, in that case I can't see how the standard topology does that.

Comment: The question would be much clearer if you defined what you meant by _continuity_ (of a set? apparently you're not referring to continuity of functions), or by _structure_ and _the real number line_

Comment: This idea of "inducing structure" is vague. I'm guessing that you've read this somewhere? Do you have a more direct quote for us to try to decipher?

Comment: I wouldn't  say it is "weak", instead of being subtle

Comment: How does defining a topology on a set allows you to take a limit is my question, I guess.

Comment: @I0_0I There is a definition of limit in a topology. With a sequence $a_n \to L$, instead of being able to set a distance $\varepsilon > 0$, and expect $a_n$ to become closer to $L$ than $\varepsilon$ eventually, you instead talk about open sets containing $L$. That is, a sequence $a_n$ tends to $L$ if, given any open set $\mathcal{U}$ containing $L$, then an $N$ exists such that $a_n \in \mathcal{U}$ for all $n \ge N$ .

Comment: @Theo Bendit if you could copy paste that comment in an answer I would accept it. It actually answers my question. Giving a topology, then we can define what a limit is.

Comment: one may interpret "continuity" of reals as a "complete linear order". Then talk about continuity using $\sup$ and $\inf$ of bounded sets (but that won't be much different than talking about limits). Different ways to look at it. Are you talking about "a topology on a set" or about "the standard topology of the reals?" If $X$ is homeomorphic to the reals (with the standard topology) then you could recover a (complete) linear order on $X$ (two possible ways), even without explicit reference to a homeomorphism (say $b$ is between $a,c$ if $a,c$ are in different components of $X\setminus\{b\}$)